# Wordpress comments logged user automatic approval

Tags: wordpress

on wordpress I wish the comments of users not logged went in a state of moderation while for logged users have the automatic approval.
How can I moderate comments on wordpress in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

There is option in `wp-admin > Settings > Discussion > Before a comment appears`

there are two options

> Comment author must have a previously approved comment

is that checked?